# How do I create this grid in HTML/CSS (no JS)

Tags: html, css

I have to implement this grid of divs. It won't change often, but it may at some point (meaning a box may be removed, and another resized). Each black box will eventually contain an image or a word, but that's not important.

How do I pull this off? Is there a more elegant way than by absolutely positioning every single box and manually entering every X/Y/width/height?

Comment: Do you use Sass? If you do, I can provide you with a great and easy answer. :)

Comment: Why did you remove the link to the image? This grid can be achieved with CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

A grid based approach would be my recommendation.
Something like: http://960.gs/

EDIT (some more options)

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/

http://cssgrid.net/